# Under what conditions is a tower of quadratic extensions a UFD, GCD domain, or just an Integral Domain?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, divisibility, principal-ideal-domains

I have been studying towers of quadratic extensions to $\mathbb Q$ and have noticed the following:

$\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ and $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2][\sqrt 3]$ are [unique factorization domains](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniqueFactorizationDomain.html)(UFDs), but $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2][\sqrt 3][\sqrt 5]$ is not because

$$
3 =\sqrt 3^2 = (\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 2)(\sqrt 5 - \sqrt 2)
$$

I have not found much literature discussing towers of quadratic extensions and their relationship to various subclasses of integral domains.  What are the conditions (if any) that towers of quadratic extensions to $\mathbb Q$ are UFDs, [GCD domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), [integrally closed domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain), or simply [integral domains](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralDomain.html)?  Is there a way to easily determine this?  I'm also unclear on how the process of [principalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principalization_(algebra)) transforms an integral domain into a UFD.  The linked article on principalization uses very dense notation that I have difficulty following and I would like an illustrating example.

Comment: You’ve put your finger into a most delicious mathematical pie. You need to read, read, read, and take as many courses as you can. As a rough approximation, let me say that the more irrationalities you adjoin to $\Bbb Q$, the less likelly it will be that you get a UFD. Meanwhile, do as much hand computation as you can, and meditate on what you’re finding.

Comment: Any suggestions on who/what/where to start reading?

Comment: @Lubin in response to your rough approximation, I can see that adding more quadratic irrationalities makes it less and less likely you will get a UFD, but do you ever stop getting a GCD Domain or ICD?

Comment: About GCD domains I’ll have to plead ignorance. But in general, when you adjoin a square root, you automatically adjoin all associated integral elements, so that the result will always be in integrally closed domain. For instance, when you adjoin $\sqrt5$ to $\Bbb Z$, you don’t get an integrally closed ring. You have to include half of $1+\sqrt5$ as well.